# mobx-state-tree Какой тип использовать, чтобы хранить картинку

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

В typescript пользовался ReturnType но в MST нужно либо создать кастомный тип либо что-то еще. В документации не нашел ничего кроме кастомного типа, но не понимаю как его написать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.